# How can I write something into crontab file from Python file?

Tags: python, cron

I try to write from a Python file cronjobs into crontab. When calling the Python file which contains the code for writing into crontab from another Python file via sudo I expect that the cronjob gets added to the crontab file but instead I get this error:

`PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/usr/bin/crontab'`

**File 1**

```py
with open('/usr/bin/crontab', 'w') as f2:
    f2.write("Hello World")
```

**File 2**

```py
import os
command = "python3 /Users/myUser/Projects2022/CronjobManager/File1.py"
os.popen("sudo -S %s"%(command), 'w').write('password')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary (executable program) for adding cronjobs is stored in `/usr/bin/crontab`. That binary actually writes your `crontab` entries in a file whose location is dependent on your OS.

On macOS, the file is in `/var/at/tabs/USERNAME`, on some systems it is in `/var/spool/cron/XXX`.

You can, and should, no more overwrite the executable at `usr/bin/crontab` than you can, or should, overwrite `/usr/bin/wc`

---

What I am saying is that you need to differentiate between:

- the program `/usr/bin/crontab` and
- the table it writes to in `/var/spool/cron/XXX`

---

What you might want to do is:

- extract the user's current crontab to a temporary file, i.e. `crontab -l > TEMPORARYFILE`
- edit or append to that file
- re-load that file back to the system, i.e. `crontab TEMPORARYFILE`

There's a good description of the `tempfile` module [here](https://pymotw.com/3/tempfile/index.html).

Comment: But how can I write something into crontab from a Python file? I see your updates on your posts. I will try something out.

Comment: You can also use https://gitlab.com/doctormo/python-crontab/

Comment: As far I have seen the package has no support for manually adding new cronjobs. It just provides functions for scheduling cron times with methods like `job.minute.every(1)` which is not what I searched for. @DiegoTorresMilano